# ng-model returned undefined in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
console.log($scope.username)

<input ng-model="username" class="user-name" placeholder="Username / Email Address">
```

not sure why my ng-model doesn't work, I got undefined. But when I test with below ng-click, it can work.

```
$scope.username = function(){
        alert('hey')
}

<input ng-click="username()" class="user-name" placeholder="Username / Email Address">
```

So strange, any thought?

Comment: What is the output of the log? In your code you log $scope.username in the first and define it as a function in the second...

Comment: We'll need more code to understand what is going on

Comment: @TedA. the first one it should already work but it doesn't. The second code I test whether ng-click work or not.

Comment: In the first one clearly $scope.username is undefined. Where is it getting declared? Where are you setting it? That's where your problem is going to be, and none of that code is here.

Comment: ng-model="username" is bind to $scope.username, and my input field has value. If I put $scope.username into an ng-click event, it will return me the value correct? but it doesn't, I got undefined.

Comment: I think we need to see your controller. So you are saying $scope.username is setting the value of your input, but then when you try to access it in a click event it is undefined? Please share the relevant part of your controller as I'm not clear on what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to assign your ng-model a function you need to use getter setter option of the ng-model

**Below is the snippet from angularjs site**

**View**

```
 <input type="text" name="userName"
             ng-model="user.name"
             ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
```

**Controller**

var _name = 'Brian';

```
$scope.user = {
    name: function(newName) {
     // Note that newName can be undefined for two reasons:
     // 1. Because it is called as a getter and thus called with no arguments
     // 2. Because the property should actually be set to undefined. This happens e.g. if the
     //    input is invalid
     return arguments.length ? (_name = newName) : _name;
    }
  };
```

> Note: For binding you can either use a normal property or a getter
>   setter function. you wont be able to use other event like functions.
>   For that you need to use ng-click, ng-init etc

For further reading

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#binding-to-a-getter-setter

**Code to acheive what you are trying to do**

```
<html ng-app="exampleApp">

<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
   <input ng-model="username" class="user-name" placeholder="Username / Email Address">

    <button ng-click="showName()">Show Name</button>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
angular.module('exampleApp', [])
    .controller('defaultCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.username = "";
        $scope.showName = function(){
            alert($scope.username)
        }
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

hope this helps!!

Comment: I don't want function, I just want my input value to be send to $scope.username.

Comment: I do the same above but it doesn't work. I have to do ng-model('username') then showName(username) then I can get the value into my function.

Comment: In that case can you include the full code in the solution or Can you create a jsfiddle and share the link. It will be much helpful to identify the problem?

Comment: On looking at the code i don't see any problem, the code that you have put in the question have no relation with the code you have used in pastebin. Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: because I changed it to a working version, I pass `ng-model='username'` to the function param like login(username).

Comment: But it's so strange I can't get $scope.username when I have ng-model='username' on the input tag.

Comment: Why would you not share the version that has the problem you are asking the question about?